# Firestore startAfterDocument() skipping documents with same Timestamp value

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having difficulty using the `startAfterDocument()` for pagination with Firestore on Flutter. It was my understanding that while `startAfter()` will simply start where the index begins a certain value, startAfterDocument() will start at the index exactly after the document given.

However, I noticed that while using `startAfterDocument()`, it is skipping documents with the same value.

For example given the following documents (date is a timestamp):

```
{id: "1", date: "4-28-2020"}
{id: "2", date: "4-29-2020"}
{id: "3", date: "4-29-2020"}
{id: "4", date: "4-29-2020"}
{id: "5", date: "4-30-2020"}
```

Using `startAfterDocument(doc3)`, I would expect the next document retrieved to be Document 4, except I'm getting document 5. It skips all the documents with the same value as given. Is this the intended functionally? Do I need to include a `.where()` to sort by the id to get this to work correctly?

EDIT:
Here's the code I'm using.

```
CollectionReference orders = Firestore.instance.collection('orders');
Query query1 = orders.orderBy('date').limit(3);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query1.getDocuments();
DocumentSnapshot lastDoc = querySnapshot.documents.last;

Query query2 = orders.orderBy('date').startAfterDocument(lastDoc).limit(3);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query2.getDocuments();
```

Using the documents given above, I get document 3 as the `lastDoc` on `query1`, then on `query2`, I get document 5 as the first document, when it should be document 4.

EDIT:

After some further testing, it seems like this is only happening with Timestamps.

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show the specific code that isn't working the way you expect, along with the source data that you're querying.  We should be able to duplicate the behavior based on what you provide.

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be related with the `orderBy`? Are you sure your query is retrieving the same order than expected? Given that some documents has the same `date`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. The orderBy is the same field for both queries. One thing I noticed with my app is that it only seems to happen with Timestamps.

Comment: Have you tried set the cursor [based on multiple values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#set_cursor_based_on_multiple_fields)? You could set your `ID` and the `Date`